# On Linux why is our pagesize so big (60GB). Does each process get a copy?

Tags: linux, oracle, memory-management

Using AWS R3.8xlarge, with 240GB, 2 oracle instances, 90GB each.  No Hugepages set up and Transparent Huge Pages are enabled.

On one of the instances doing proc/meminfo we see

PageTables:     60709140 kB

Why would the pagesize be so high?  What causes a pagetable to increase to that point.  Does each process get a copy as noted in various web sites (doesn't seem possible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Oracle there is one dedicated session process per connection. Each process accesses SGA(shared memory segments). So when you take SGA size, divide it by 4096B (page size) and multiply it by amount of concurrent db connections.
You get an amount of mapped SGA pages. This number can be huge.

Note: Oracle recommends to use HugePages and disable Transparent HugePages. This will make SGA non-swappable. This will make Linux memory management much simpler.